# Flutter: Show snackbar based on user's internet connectivity

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter home screen content widget, On which I am trying to show snackbar when user loses internet connection. There are screens that are available offline and user does not need internet connection, So those screen won't show the snackbar.
**
Current approach**: I used a consumer on home screen content widget and used a helper function to show this snackbar.

**Issue**: The issue I am facing is that this snackbar is showing on other screens as well even though the consumer is added only on home screen widget yet. (Regardless other screen should be available offline or not).

Home screen widget:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BuildContext homeContext = context;
    
    return  Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Consumer<ConnectivityProvider>(
                builder: (context, connectivityProvider, _) {   
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                            future: fetchHomeScreenData(Localizations.localeOf(context).toString()),
                            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                              
                              AppHelper.toggleConnectivitySnackbar(homeContext, connectivityProvider, _);

                              final result = AppHelper.apiResponseHandler(context, snapshot);
      
                              if (result != null) {
                                return result;
                              }
      
                              
                              return Column(children: [
                                Consumer<FirebaseSubscriptionProvider>(
                                  builder: (context, firebaseSubscriptionProvider, _){
                                    firebaseSubscriptionProvider.loadSubscriptionTopics();

                                    final isSubscribed = firebaseSubscriptionProvider.isTopicSubscribed('new_post') ;
                                    final subscriptionColor = isSubscribed ? AppColors.orange : AppColors.green;
                                    return Container();
                                    
                                  }
                                ),
                                
                                
                              ]);
                            },
                          ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

The helper function which handles showing/hiding snackbar:

```
static void toggleConnectivitySnackbar(BuildContext context, ConnectivityProvider connectivityProvider)
  {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (!connectivityProvider.isConnected) {
        print("Helper Showing Snackbar on ${ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name}");
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.no_internet_connection),
            duration: const Duration(days: 1),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
          ),
        );
      }
      else{
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
      }
    });
  }
```

Route generator:

```
class AppRouter {
  static Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings, BuildContext? context) {
    
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return AppMainScreen.route();
     
     case SelectLanguageScreen.routeName:
        return SelectLanguageScreen.route();

      default:
        return errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: const RouteSettings(name: '/error'),
      builder: (_){
        return const Scaffold(
          appBar: AppMainAppbar(),
          body: Center(
            child: Icon(Icons.warning_outlined, size: 100.0, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use a ConnectivityProvider consumer only home screen widget yet. I expected it to work only on home page but its triggering on all screens. The issue is in helper function "toggleConnectivitySnackbar" the route name is always "/" even on other screens. To address this issue I tried global key and tried to pass the home screen context but both did not help.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I created a getx controller to notify the user of the current network connection ,but if you need to show the snack bar in specific screen then you need add check if the user is in that screen

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:drive_master/helpers/common_helpers.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

class ConnectionStatusController extends GetxController {
  static final ConnectionStatusController _singleton =
      ConnectionStatusController._internal();

  factory ConnectionStatusController() => _singleton;

  ConnectionStatusController._internal();

  bool hasConnection = false;

  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  final RxBool connectionStatus = false.obs;

  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult>? _connectivitySubscription;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _initialize();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    _dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }

  Stream<bool> get connectionChange => connectionStatus.stream;

  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    _connectivitySubscription = _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(
      _connectionChange,
    );
    await checkConnection();
  }

  void _dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription?.cancel();
  }

  void _connectionChange(ConnectivityResult result) {
    checkConnection();
  }

  Future<void> checkConnection() async {
    bool previousConnection = hasConnection;

    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      hasConnection = result.isNotEmpty && result.first.rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      hasConnection = false;
    }

    if (previousConnection != hasConnection) {
      connectionStatus.value = hasConnection;
    }
    Logger().f("Network conncection ${connectionStatus.value}");
    if (!connectionStatus.value) {
      CommonHelpers.showToast("No internet Please Check You Connection");
    } else {
//have network
    }
  }
}
```

in my main.dart i used  `Get.put(ConnectionStatusController());` to initiate the stream